# PDFs are not embedded with IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, iframe, adobe

I created a simple html file that was supposed to have an embedded pdf that was printable:

```
<p>Try to print this sucka!</p>
<div>
    <iframe id="frmPdf" src="ImageDir/temp.pdf" style="width:0px; height:0px;"></iframe>
    <button id="btnPrint" onclick="frmPdf.contentWindow.focus(); frmPdf.contentWindow.print(); return false;">Push Me To Print</button>
</div>
```

This works fine on Chrome. I can print the document. However, on IE when I load the page I immediately get a download/save prompt at the bottom of the Window and the print button does nothing. If I enlarge the iframe I see that there is nothing in it at all.

I suspect this is an Adobe plugin problem. I downloaded the latest reader (DC) and installed it, then uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Then I disabled and re-enabled the plugin, but nothing works.

I opened the Preferences in Adobe Reader DC and went to the "Internet" section. The following options are enabled:

- Display in Read Mode by default
- Allow fast web view
- Allow speculative downloading in the background

It also says that the product available for use by browsers is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe. However, when I open IE and go to the information for the adobe plugin, it says it is using C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Acrobat\ActiveX\AcroPDF64.dll. I don't know what that means.

How do I make the PDF plugin work?

Comment: I recall something about this. I think you have to use the 32bit version browser. My guess is you are running the 64bit

Comment: Yeah running 64bit. I eventually just decided to abandon this approach and embed the PDF into an HTTP response.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say embed into a http response?

Comment: @Normajean - I don't even remember.